# What does "offer reals" mean in this hadith?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, hadith-interpretation, arabic-translation

I want to know the background of this Hadith:

1. What does it mean "Um Haran bint Milhan, who would **offer him reals**"?
2. Does this mean the prophet slept in her house. What type of relationship was it ?

> **عَنْ أَنَسِ بْنِ مَالِكٍ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ أَنَّهُ سَمِعَهُ يَقُولُ كَانَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم يَدْخُلُ عَلَى أُمِّ حَرَامٍ
>   بِنْتِ مِلْحَانَ، فَتُطْعِمُهُ، وَكَانَتْ أُمُّ حَرَامٍ تَحْتَ
>   عُبَادَةَ بْنِ الصَّامِتِ، فَدَخَلَ عَلَيْهَا رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله
>   عليه وسلم فَأَطْعَمَتْهُ وَجَعَلَتْ تَفْلِي رَأْسَهُ، فَنَامَ رَسُولُ
>   اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ثُمَّ اسْتَيْقَظَ وَهُوَ يَضْحَكُ‏.‏
>   قَالَتْ فَقُلْتُ وَمَا يُضْحِكُكَ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ قَالَ ‏"‏ نَاسٌ
>   مِنْ أُمَّتِي عُرِضُوا عَلَىَّ، غُزَاةً فِي سَبِيلِ اللَّهِ،
>   يَرْكَبُونَ ثَبَجَ هَذَا الْبَحْرِ، مُلُوكًا عَلَى الأَسِرَّةِ، أَوْ
>   مِثْلُ الْمُلُوكِ عَلَى الأَسِرَّةِ ‏"‏‏.‏ شَكَّ إِسْحَاقُ‏.‏ قَالَتْ
>   فَقُلْتُ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ ادْعُ اللَّهَ أَنْ يَجْعَلَنِي
>   مِنْهُمْ‏.‏ فَدَعَا لَهَا رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ثُمَّ
>   وَضَعَ رَأْسَهُ، ثُمَّ اسْتَيْقَظَ وَهُوَ يَضْحَكُ فَقُلْتُ وَمَا
>   يُضْحِكُكَ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ قَالَ ‏"‏ نَاسٌ مِنْ أُمَّتِي عُرِضُوا
>   عَلَىَّ، غُزَاةً فِي سَبِيلِ اللَّهِ ‏"‏‏.‏ كَمَا قَالَ فِي
>   الأَوَّلِ‏.‏ قَالَتْ فَقُلْتُ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ، ادْعُ اللَّهَ أَنْ
>   يَجْعَلَنِي مِنْهُمْ‏.‏ قَالَ ‏"‏ أَنْتِ مِنَ الأَوَّلِينَ ‏"‏‏.‏
>   فَرَكِبَتِ الْبَحْرَ فِي زَمَانِ مُعَاوِيَةَ بْنِ أَبِي سُفْيَانَ،
>   فَصُرِعَتْ عَنْ دَابَّتِهَا**
>
> Allah's Apostle used to visit Um Haran bint Milhan, **who would offer
>   him reals**. Um-Haram was the wife of Ubada bin As-Samit. Allah's
>   Apostle, once visited her and she provided him with food and started
>   looking for lice in his head. **Then Allah's Apostle slept, and
>   afterwards woke up smiling**. Um Haran asked, "What causes you to smile,
>   O Allah's Apostle?" He said. "Some of my followers who (in a dream)
>   were presented before me as fighters in Allah's Cause (on board a
>   ship) amidst this sea cause me to smile; they were as kings on the
>   thrones (or like kings on the thrones)." (Ishaq, a sub-narrator is not
>   sure as to which expression the Prophet used.) Um-Haram said, "O
>   Allah's Apostle! Invoke Allah that he makes me one of them. **Allah's
>   Apostle invoked Allah for her and slept again and woke up smiling.**
>   Once again Um Haram asked, "What makes you smile, O Allah's Apostle?"
>   He replied, "Some of my followers were presented to me as fighters in
>   Allah's Cause," repeating the same dream. Um-Haram said, "O Allah's
>   Apostle! Invoke Allah that He makes me one of them." He said, "You are
>   amongst the first ones." It happened that she sailed on the sea during
>   the Caliphate of Mu'awlya bin Abi Sufyan, and after she disembarked,
>   she fell down from her riding animal and died. [Volume 4, Book 52, Number 47 ]

Comment: "Reals" is a misprint for "meals".

Answer (score 5):

Answer your second question:

That the Prophet Muharram to Um Haran bint Milhan.

Their relationship either by blood or breastfeeding ...

Al-Nawawi said:

> ((اِتَّفَقَ الْعُلَمَاء عَلَى أَنَّهَا كَانَتْ
>   مَحْرَمًا لَهُ صَلَّى اللَّه عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ , وَاخْتَلَفُوا فِي
>   كَيْفِيَّة ذَلِكَ فَقَالَ اِبْن عَبْد الْبَرّ وَغَيْره: كَانَتْ
>   إِحْدَى خَالَاته مِنْ الرَّضَاعَة , وَقَالَ آخَرُونَ: بَلْ كَانَتْ
>   خَالَة لِأَبِيهِ أَوْ لِجَدِّهِ ; لِأَنَّ عَبْد الْمُطَّلِب كَانَتْ
>   أُمّه مِنْ بَنِي النَّجَّار))
>
> The scholars are agreed that it was taboo (Mohrram) to him peace be upon him,
>   and they differ in how to do so; Ibn Abd al-Barr and others: One aunts
>   of breastfeeding, and others have said: it was aunt to his father or
>   his grandfather; because Abdulmutallab mother was from Bani Najjar.
>
> [Book: Explanation of Al-Nawawi to sahih Muslim, page: 51]

Also Al-Nawawi said:

> ((وكانت أُمّ سُلَيْم هذه هي وأختها خالتين لرسولِ الله مِنْ جِهةِ
>   الرَّضَاعَ))
>
> And "Om Salim" and her sister (Um Haran bint Milhan) were aunts to the
>   Messenger of Allah on the one hand breastfeeding.

Comment: breast feeding is probably not true, [this link](http://www.roshd.org/eng/beliefs/?BEL_CODE=128#No1) say the prophet was breast feeded by Amina (Mother), Thuwaybah (nurse) and Halima (RA) (nurse)

Comment: Yes, there is a difference in that ..."and others have said: it was aunt to his father or his grandfather; because Abdulmutallab mother was from Bani Najjar.".

Comment: but that would not make her muharram because she is not a direct aunt.

Comment: No !!, that not true !!!
If my aunt muharram, So aunt of my father or grandfather also muharram necessarily

Answer (score 4):

The phrase "who would offer him reals" is a mistranslation; the Arabic term used (according to [sunnah.com](http://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/56#7)) is `فتطعمه`.

The verb `طعم` (meaning "to eat") has as it's Form IV the verb `أطعم`, which is a reflexive version of the root verb; for example, instead of "to eat", `أطعم` would mean "to cause to eat".  In other words, "to feed".

`تطعم` is the singular third-person feminine imperfect conjunction of the above, that is to say "she feeds" or "she will feed".  (This construction could *also* be the second-person masculine imperfect of the same, which would translate as the imperative "Feed," but that translation seems unlikely in context.)

The `ه` suffix is a simple pronoun ("him") referring to the target of the verb, thus `تطعمه` would mean "she will feed him".

The particle `ف` prefixing the word doesn't really translate cleanly; it is used to connect clauses but it's purpose is more grammatic than vocabularic.  Depending on context, it may be directly translated as "and", "then" or "so," but this list is hardly exhaustive.

All-in-all, the first sentence of this hadith would be much better translated as,

> Allah's Apostle used to visit Um Haran bint Milhan, who would offer him meals.

And to answer your second question, eating food is not necessarily correlated with sleeping, beyond possibly feeling drowsy after a large meal.